# HP Server Gen9 with Gen8 Caddies/Trays

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hard-drive

If I have an Generation 9 (Gen9) server from HP, will I be able to use the Gen8 hard disk caddies/trays?

For example if I get a *HP ProLiant DL180 Gen9* will the old Gen8 caddies/trays still be compatible?

[It seems](https://serverfault.com/questions/401976/are-new-hp-gen8-servers-compatible-with-g7-drives) that between Gen7 and Gen8 the caddies got "smart" and thus weren't compatible, just wondering if there was a similar change between Gen8 and Gen9 as well.

Additionally do only specific HDD work with these caddies/trays or would a normal WD Red work as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. The carriers are the same between Gen8 and Gen9 systems.

No, don't use non-HP disks... especially cheap SATA.

Because this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Is the "non-HP disks" a recommendation or are there technical limits to it?

Comment: @Lukas It depends on your luck. They could either work without issue, or spawn error messages like above or just *not work at all*.