# HP Server doesn't boot when disk is in caddy

Tags: hp, hp-proliant, hp-smart-array

We have recently bought an unused `HP DL320e G8 v2` and decided to use some of the `Western Digitial RE 3TB SATA` disks we have in stock for our other hardware with HP Drive caddy's.
At first we thought this was working correctly but for some reason the system is unstable when the caddy/LED ribbon cable (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQRRr.png) is connected to the server.
The server won't boot to Intelligent Provisioning anymore (for configuring RAID) and things like installing an OS won't work either when it hits the part where it would check the drives.

Here's the strange thing.. When we boot the server itself when the ribbon cable is disconnected from the server/caddy the server boots fine and everything works as expected (without the activity LED's on the drives.)

What would be the reason for this? Doesn't HP allow booting non-HP drives from their caddy's or is there something I'm missing here.

Server Info:

- Proliant DL320e Gen8 v2
- 32GB DDR3 ECC @ 1600 Mhz
- B120i Smart Array Controller 5.50
- ROM P80 04/02/2015
- Intelligent Provisioning 1.62.31

Answer (score 0):

- Where did you acquire HP drive caddies?
- It sounds like you went out of your way to NOT use HP disks.
- You really shouldn't use non-HP disks in Gen8/Gen9 servers.

See: [HP Server Gen9 with Gen8 Caddies/Trays](https://serverfault.com/questions/665254/hp-server-gen9-with-gen8-caddies-trays/665262#665262)

Comment: - Caddies where acquired from a local hardware store by a colleague of mine, they look genuine HP. - We have good expierence with the 3TB RE drives from Western Digitial, that's why we choose them.. Sounds like HP is in this case the problem since the disks work fine on any RAID controller we've used before.

Comment: HP doesn't officially sell the caddies separately. Either way, the drives you're using are not compatible.